# QLineEdit accepting only integers and ” and / characters?

Tags: qt, qt4, qlineedit, qregexp

I have a `QLineEdit` and I am using it for a measurement conversion application. In that `QLineEdit` I have to use only integer values, so I used the `QDoubleValidator`.

```
q_LineEdit->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(this));
```

Now I want the `QLineEdit` to accept only " and / characters to it, as well as the integers, as it is required for the conversion application. How can I make my `QLineEdit` accept it while using a `QDoubleValidator`?

**Note:** I want my `QLineEdit` to accept something like this (eg. **70“1/2**).

**Note:** The `QLineEdit` should not accept any other characters other than " and /.

Answer (score 4):

At last I figured out the answer by myself. It's very simple. Just use `QRegExpValidator`.
Here's my piece of code:

```
QRegExp rx("(|\"|/|\\.|[0-9]){30}");
m_LineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(rx, this));
```

Comment: You could also use QRegExp or QRegularExpression to fix precisely what is accepted or not in your QLabel. The regexp you provide allows '"""70""1/21/5"12"/51/"5"65//' as a valid value ;)
`QRegExp rx("[0-9]{2}\"[0-9]\/[0-9]");` is probably better, you just have to fix how many numbers you accept at each step